# OnActivityResult called before OnClick

Tags: android

I am trying to create an intent to open the Gallery (which works fine).

However, I need to change the image button to show the image of the picture selected by the user.

The problem is that onActivityResult() method is being called before the galleryIntent() method which is resulting in the result code not being RESULT_OK therefore when the picture is selected, the user is redirected to the application and nothing happens.

```
public class DataEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton imgButton;
Bitmap bmp;
private static final int PICTURE_SELECTED = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.bernine.practicalsessions.R.layout.activity_portal);
    imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.bernine.practicalsessions.R.id.imageButton1);
}

//Method to start the intent upon clicking the imageButton
public void galleryIntent(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_SELECTED);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Opened Before", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            imgButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result not ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

I tried doing android:launchMode="standard" in the activity in the manifest but did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `onActivityResult` should only be called *after* the intent has returned.

Comment: Maybe you should check for requestCode == PICTURE_SELECTED inside of onActivityResult

Comment: Yes however, the method that is first triggered is the onActivityResult then it executes the intent. in fact when the image button is selected a message shows "Image opened before" and "Result not ok" (I did this for debugging purposes), then the gallery is opened

Comment: From where you are invoking galleryIntent(). It is not anywhere in your posted code.

Comment: It is being invoked from the XML file  <ImageButton android:onClick="galleryIntent"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to start a new task for picture selection -

```
public void galleryIntent(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    **//Remove this line** 
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_SELECTED);
}
```